# ResultSet in Transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I've got a method which returns me a `ResultSet` object:

```
  @Repository
  public class SomeDAOImpl implements SomeDAO{
    @Override
    public ResultSet getSomething()
    {
     ...
    }
  }
```

And this is how I call that:

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService{
   @Autowired
   private SomeDAO someDAO;

   @Transactional
   @Override
   public void doSomething()
   {
      someDAO.getSomething();
      ...
   }
}
```

Questions:

1. Do I have to close ResultSet?
2. Is it ok to return ResultSet object?

Comment: better if you extract data from resultset & return custom class object. & using query you get data or by hibernate object ? if using query use `Spring JdbcTemplate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Yes you should close a ResultSet.

2 I suggest you to return an Object and not a ResultSet.

Here a draft as should be... [Here](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-jdbc-transactions-example) a tutorial.

```
@Repository
public class SomeDAOImpl implements SomeDAO{

        @Override
        public User getSomething(String username){
            User user = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USERNAME = ?",
            new Object[] { username },
            new UserMapper()
            );
           return user;
        }

        private class UserMapper implements RowMapper<User>{

        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
            user.setUsername(rs.getString("USERNAME"));
            user.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
            return user;
        }

     }

}
```